# Problema al convertir interferencia a diferencia de conjuntos? - c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

hice un código en c++ el cual hace una intersección de conjuntos, quisiera poder realizar una diferencia de conjuntos más abajo dejo lo que casi pude realizar pero me da unos errores, Ya que al colocar cantidades grandes números o más datos no me lo realiza de forma correcta. Estos los tengo que hacer con arreglos.

**Intersección**
Este no me da problema, pero lo use de guía para poder realizar la diferencia de conjuntos, se los comparto para que puedan relacionarlos.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


main(){
    int n,m,a=0,C[100];
    
    //Conjunto A
    cout<<"Ingrese el tamano del conjunto A: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout << endl;
    
    
    int A[n];
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese el dato "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    
    
    //conjunto B
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese el tamano del conjunto B: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout << endl;
    
    
    int B[m];
    
    
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese el dato "<<j+1<<" :";
        cin>>B[j];
    }
    
    
    
    
    //Intersección
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            
            if(A[i]==B[j])
            {
        C[a]=A[i];  
        a++;
            }//cierra if
        
        }//cierra for j
     
    }//cierra for i
    
  
    

    
    cout<<"\n\nInterseccion: \n";
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
       cout<<C[i]<<endl;
 
    }   
    
}//cierra main
```

**Diferencia**
Como explicaba arriba, al ingresar muchos datos o cantidades grandes no me hace la diferencia, hay veces que me da un valor 0 como si los estuviera restando. Solo me ha funcionado con colocar cantidades pequeñas y pocos datos.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;



int contador = 0;


//Permite ingresar datos A
int *IngresarA( int *A , int N)
{
 A = new int [1000];
 
 for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
     {

      cout << "Ingrese el dato " << i+1 << " : ";
      cin >> A[i];
     }
 
 return A;
      
}

//Permite ingresar datos B
int *IngresarB( int *B , int N)
{
 B = new int [1000];
 
 for(int j=0 ; j<N ; j++)
     {

      cout << "Ingrese el dato " << j+1 << " : ";
      cin >> B[j];
     }
 
 return B;
      
}


//realiza la diferencia
int *Diferencia( int *A , int *B , int *C , int N ,int M )
{
 
 C = new int [1000];
  
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (A[i] > 0 and not (B[i] > 0))
            C[contador++]= A[i];

    return C;
}





//muestra el resultado
void Mostrar( int *A , int N)
{
 
 cout << " " << A[0];
 
 for(int i=1; i<N; i++)
      cout << " , " << A[i];
      
}





int main()
{

 int N, M;
 
 int *A = NULL;
 int *B = NULL;
 int *C = NULL;
 
 cout << "Ingrese el tamano del conjunto A  : ";
 cin >> N;
 cout << endl;
 
 A = IngresarA(A , N);
 

 
 
 cout << "\n\nIngrese el tamano del conjunto B : ";
 cin >> M;
 cout << endl;
 
 B = IngresarB(B , M);


 
 
 C = Diferencia( A , B , C , N , M );
 cout << "\n\nDiferencia = ";
 Mostrar(C,contador);
 
 
 cout << endl<<endl;
 system("pause");
}
```

***El código me funciona cuando:***

**en el conjunto A agrego 5 datos:**

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

**en el conjunto B agrego 5 datos:**

1, 2, 3

[image: ADJUNTO CUANDO ME FUNCIONA]

***No me funciona al colocar:***

**en el conjunto A agrego 5 datos:**

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

**en el conjunto B agrego 5 datos:**

1, 2, 3, 6, 7

[image: ADJUNTO CUANDO NO FUNCIONA]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los datos que introduces, cuáles son los datos que obtienes, qué datos esperabas recibir?

Comment: Buenas, agregue más datos y unas imágenes en la pregunta. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estoy entendiendo bien tu código, lo que pretendes es obtener los elementos que no son comunes a ambos conjuntos. Si es eso en el primer caso tu código funciona por casualidad no por lógica.

Únicamente compruebas que cada elemento del primer conjunto sea mayor a cero a la vez que cada elemento del segundo conjunto (en la misma posición) no sea mayor a cero:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    if (A[i] > 0 and not (B[i] > 0))
        C[contador++]= A[i];
```

Esa algorítmica no tiene ningún parecido a la idea de diferencia de conjuntos que intentas expresar... se parecen tanto como El Quijote y el manual de un Microondas. La algorítmica que buscas es la siguiente:

1. Toma un valor del primer conjunto.
2. Comprueba si dicho valor no está en **ninguna** posición del segundo conjunto.

   1. Si lo anterior se cumple, es una diferencia.
3. Pasar al siguiente elemento del primer conjunto.

Puedes conseguir eso con un código parecido a este:

```
for (int indice_A = 0; indice_A != N; ++indice_A)
{
    bool encontrado = false;

    for (int indice_B = 0; !encontrado && (indice_B != N); ++indice_B)
    {
        encontrado = A[indice_A] == B[indice_B];
    }

    if (!encontrado)
        c[indice_C++] = A[indice_A];
}
```

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas, tu código tiene errores mucho más graves que la algorítmica:

1. Estás pidiendo memoria dinámica sin necesidad.
2. Estás pasando a funciones punteros por copia para ser modificados dentro de la función, haciendo que el cambio sea local a la función.
3. Esas funciones reciben el puntero para modificarlo y a la vez lo devuelven, decídete por una manera de compartir datos.
4. Usas variables globales si necesidad.
5. Repites código haciendo funciones idénticas para tratar datos idénticos pero en otra variable.
6. `main` debe devolver un valor al acabar.
7. No liberas la memoria que solicitas.

Si arreglamos todos tus problemas de lógica y algorítmica, redactando tu código como C++ moderno, podrías obtener algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* Sólo necesitamos la cantidad de datos, el vector se crea dentro y
es devuelto por la función */
std::vector<int> Ingresar(int cantidad)
{
    // Creamos un vector con 'cantidad' datos inicializados a cero
    std::vector<int> datos(cantidad, 0);

    // Pedimos cada dato
    int indice = 0;
    for (auto &dato : datos)
    {
        std::cout << "Ingrese el dato " << ++indice << " : ";
        std::cin >> dato;
    }

    return datos;
}

/* Sólo necesitamos los vectores a comparar, se reciben como referencia para
evitar copias y se reciben como constante porque sólo los leeremos, el vector
de diferencia es devuelto por la función */
std::vector<int> Diferencia(const std::vector<int> &A, const std::vector<int> &B)
{
    std::vector<int> diferencia;

    for (const auto &a : A)
    {
        bool encontrado = false;

        for (const auto &b : B)
        {
            if (encontrado = a == b)
                break;
        }

        if (!encontrado)
            diferencia.push_back(a);
    }

    return diferencia;
}

int main()
{
    int tamano_A = 0;
    std::cout << "Ingrese el tamano del conjunto A  : ";
    std::cin >> tamano_A;
    std::cout << std::endl;
 
    const auto A = Ingresar(tamano_A);
 
    int tamano_B = 0;
    std::cout << "Ingrese el tamano del conjunto B  : ";
    std::cin >> tamano_B;
    std::cout << std::endl;
 
    const auto B = Ingresar(tamano_B);

    std::cout << "\n\nDiferencia = ";
    for (const auto &diferencia : Diferencia(A, B))
        std::cout << diferencia << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNbxoxED2vf8WUSmE3oSX9yIUFJLa95Fap10iR8Q6pm8Xe2l6ktMqvyk/ID6NjG5YFQtX2AMLeN/PezHuLqOs3d0Ks16@lElVTIoylts4gX07Z7m6FwmkzZWx4Dl@fnyoNCgVa6fhSW6g4CK6cLHkJhC6503YAWEEsA4sgqCM9U85oeGBo6feqwcppqAlADRaNEvL5ScH5kFlXjkaxdiyVm8K1ujNouUnp1FJl7BdLhkP45MWSikZt@YRW0N/C@lEPSCWF5JX8yUs6kWI0miVHVAGcbosHcJnlLNB8wVJ6GsFLHlAs8WqkKqVAmMBlzpIFkae8oanOPAJGsV3GEpIauYRuHIzH0IszoV9TwPb87cXFpp9HUHkvb@ukgmmUR3ePpMmga4yKDDl7POUNfeJ8GKbWy5obbgbeFINCzlH5S02HBRokEzh4BMMVdfC7rCW38HCEpyVbR2tC7@CPBsEGbs9XIXVa7mWA@VzIluFfA/C5LU0DLxwhzmYDOPWoCFE5trpt6i0O3sUO0UFO@59trJtrXQFBNQWY8kN2L3hl0dcdF86pkCiTUJnIBaR7lRwmE5j759SXsnvvPfaGBuirHTZAdiLf1o39djvn4j7l2UEGOpPQtc/lkkuVhrn9ibLAlb6dbXJ6MokRR95UfpnfG0XzzGATxG4Otw0Pm4UDqrLKGbCksxVP3b7G2@osoDoCi/8RWPxBYPHXAosXBBbh5d8Xc6Nu1C6OVNTLXwhPJ@ujbnoppUWWHf4ZdNB06kM/33lL63hcr6/YO/aefWAf2RV9x9@/AQ)</kbd>.